# Is it possible to see how much data lives within the events of firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I am trying to see how much data I have been collecting within firebase so I can plan for pricing when sending to bigquery. I do not have any firestore set up either.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all of your records including reads and writes in the Firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com).

Via code, to see how many records are in a collection, you can read the whole collection (don't forget each document counts as a read here) and then check the size of the object returned.